# Can R display how many changes were made to a variable like Stata does

Tags: r, output, stata

When one is, e.g., replacing a variable in Stata, the Stata output will say that x real changes were made to the variable. This is very useful to know. Is there any similar functionality in R?

Comment: example of input/output and also why this would be useful? do you mean like the warning in this example? `x <- factor(1:2); x[2] <- 3`

Comment: what kind of change to a variable are you referring to? reassigning the variable? applying a function to it?

Comment: Basically when you have a variable `x` from which you generate a new variable `x2`, is there anywhere in R where that relationship is displayed. In stata, that newly created variable is often shown to be generated from x. Is there something like that in R?

Comment: Abdou, Yes, that is what I meant. rawr and plafort, I was thinking more along the lines of @Konrad's example. Essentially have a vector or data frame, do something to it, and then see how many elements have changed. Obviously R and Stata are very different and have different aims. Konrad's answer is a good one and gets at what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could achieve the desired results by simply comparing newly created vectors and tabulating the results:

```
A <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
B <- c("A", "C", "C", "E")
A == B
# OR
table(A == B)
```

In effect, you should be able to save your transformations as a new column/vector and then compare with the original object, summarising `TRUE/FALSE` values should provide you with the desired information on how many values were changed.

***Full output***

```
> A <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
> B <- c("A", "C", "C", "E")
> A == B
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> table(A == B)["TRUE"]
TRUE 
   2 
> table(A == B)

FALSE  TRUE 
    2     2
```